# Using scipy solve_bvp for a nonhomogeneous ODE

Tags: scipy, ode

I am trying to solve the following 4th order BVP

y'''' = K - C*y

My x variable is a linspace with 100 nodes. As you can see, K is a vector of the same length=100 and makes the equation nonhomogeneous. When I press solve, however, there is the following error:

```
Cell In [11], line 18, in fun(x, y)
     17 def fun(x, y):
---> 18     ans = vector-np.multiply(C,y[0])
     19     return np.vstack((y[1],y[2],y[3],ans))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (99,)
```

Why does the solver suddenly change the length of y by 1 and how can I fix this error?

EDIT: I must add that the solver works fine when K is absent i.e. the equation is homogeneous.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import numpy as np
    
L = 10 
nodes = 100

A = 1000
B = 1500
C = 0.05

x = np.linspace(0,L,nodes)

vector = np.ones(nodes)

def fun(x, y):
    ans = vector-np.multiply(C,y[0])
    return np.vstack((y[1],y[2],y[3],ans))

def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[2], yb[2], ya[3]+A/B, yb[3]])

y_a = np.zeros((4, x.size))

res_a = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_a)


res1 = res_a.sol(x)[0]
res2 = res_a.sol(x)[1]
res3 = B*res_a.sol(x)[2]
res4 = B*res_a.sol(x)[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solver establishes in the first round a system for polynomial approximations over the `nodes-1=99` segments of the first subdivision.

There is no guarantee that the subdivision remains unchanged in the later solver rounds. So your ODE right-side function has to work with arbitrary `x` arrays. This means that parameters given as a function table need to be interpolated for the general `x` array. There are procedures in `numpy.interp` for instantaneous interpolation and `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to generate interpolation functions.